# Meaning of a number in a Fortran format string

Tags: fortran, format

I am analysing a Fortran code and I would like to get informations about the writting of final results at the end of code. Below the code snippet:

```
! Store solution into file
   open(1,file='outputSeq.dat',action='write',status='replace')
   do j=0,size_y+1
     write(1,999) (x0(i,j),i=0,size_x+1)
   end do
   close(1)

999 format(1000(f15.11,1x))
```

I don't know the signification of `1000(f15.11,1x)` and more precisely the number `1000` in front of `(f15.11,1x)` : what does it mean?

I thought initially that it would correspond on the same line to the number of floats (`f15.11`) plus a space (`1x`) for each float but I made tests with writting more than `1000` elements on the same line and the writting is well performed.

Comment: The 1000 is a _repeat count specifier_.  If `size_x` is greater than 998 you should be seeing a difference (albeit hard to see).

Comment: @francescalus Is it possible to put a variable equal to `size_x` instead of `1000` : this way, I could automatically adjust the format without having to modify format and recompiling.

Comment: You can search for (alternatives to) variable formats, but in this case you could replace 1000 with just a very large number (again, searching can explain that) or even `*`.  (I've lousy connection, otherwise I'd probably find links.)

Comment: thanks, `*` does the trick

Comment: note the "*" is a "new" feature (f2003 maybe?). That's why you'll see the "big number" approach in old code.

Comment: @agentp ok, good to know it

Comment: @agentp IIRC f2008